# Can I install a recent gcc from binaries on Amazon Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, gcc, amazon-linux

I'm using Amazon Linux on an EC2 instance started from the most recent 2017.03 AMI ([ami-6df1e514](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2017.03-release-notes/)).

This distribution comes with `g++` 4.8.3 from 2013. I need something more recent that can compile C++14.

Is there any way to install a more recent `gcc` from some sort of binaries, or am I stuck compiling it from source?

I'm not seeing anything in the Amazon repos that looks recent:

```
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ yum list \*gcc\*
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Installed Packages
gcc.noarch                                                   4.8.3-3.20.amzn1                                      @amzn-main
gcc-c++.noarch                                               4.8.3-3.20.amzn1                                      @amzn-main
gcc-gfortran.noarch                                          4.8.3-3.20.amzn1                                      @amzn-main
gcc48.x86_64                                                 4.8.3-9.111.amzn1                                     @amzn-main
gcc48-c++.x86_64                                             4.8.3-9.111.amzn1                                     @amzn-main
gcc48-gfortran.x86_64                                        4.8.3-9.111.amzn1                                     @amzn-main
libgcc48.x86_64                                              4.8.3-9.111.amzn1                                     installed 
Available Packages
gcc-gnat.noarch                                              4.8.3-3.20.amzn1                                      amzn-main 
gcc44.x86_64                                                 4.4.6-4.81.amzn1                                      amzn-main 
gcc44-c++.x86_64                                             4.4.6-4.81.amzn1                                      amzn-main 
gcc44-gfortran.x86_64                                        4.4.6-4.81.amzn1                                      amzn-main 
gcc44-gnat.x86_64                                            4.4.6-4.81.amzn1                                      amzn-main 
gcc44-objc.x86_64                                            4.4.6-4.81.amzn1                                      amzn-main 
gcc44-objc++.x86_64                                          4.4.6-4.81.amzn1                                      amzn-main 
gcc48-gnat.x86_64                                            4.8.3-9.111.amzn1                                     amzn-main 
gcc48-plugin-devel.x86_64                                    4.8.3-9.111.amzn1                                     amzn-main 
libgcc44.i686                                                4.4.6-4.81.amzn1                                      amzn-main 
libgcc44.x86_64                                              4.4.6-4.81.amzn1                                      amzn-main 
libgcc48.i686                                                4.8.3-9.111.amzn1                                     amzn-main
```

Is there an alternative, testing repo or something that contains more recent packages?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Many packages available for Amazon Linux are out of date. The best approach is to use Ubuntu. If you have to start with AL your options are to find a repository that's up to date (Centos) or build from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new Amazon Linux 2 at https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/ which has gcc v7.2.1 in it's default repo.

Comment: gcc 7.3.1 as of Sep 2018.

Comment: gcc7 fails to build my codebase, we need gcc8. how to do now

Comment: Try linuxbrew https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

Answer (score 0):

Currently it looks like that:

```sh
# yum list \*gcc10\*
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Installed Packages
gcc10.x86_64                                   10.3.1-1.amzn2.0.1                    @amzn2-core
gcc10-binutils.x86_64                          2.35-21.amzn2.0.1                     @amzn2-core
gcc10-binutils-gold.x86_64                     2.35-21.amzn2.0.1                     @amzn2-core
Available Packages
gcc10-binutils.i686                            2.35-21.amzn2.0.1                     amzn2-core 
gcc10-binutils-devel.x86_64                    2.35-21.amzn2.0.1                     amzn2-core 
gcc10-c++.x86_64                               10.3.1-1.amzn2.0.1                    amzn2-core 
gcc10-gdb-plugin.x86_64                        10.3.1-1.amzn2.0.1                    amzn2-core 
gcc10-plugin-devel.x86_64                      10.3.1-1.amzn2.0.1                    amzn2-core
```

Therefore just execute:
`yum install -y gcc10.x86_64 gcc10-c++.x86_64` and check it:

````sh
# gcc10-gcc --version
gcc10-gcc (GCC) 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.```
````